# SQL database in status SUSPECT

Tags: sql-server

I had a database in status SUSPECT (No items).  I have not Backup. I've only .mdf and .ldf files.
After reading all answer regarding this topic, I executed all commands to fix this status, but without success.
I also executed the following commands for recovering my database :

```
sp_detach_db 'Mydb'
```

and the following message:

> "Successfully detached database 'Mydb'." )

then executed 
    sp_attach_db @dbname = N'Mydb', 
       @filename1 = N'E:\MSSQL7\Data\Mydb_Data.MDF', 
       @filename2 = N'E:\MSSQL7\Data\Mydb_Log.LDF'

and the following error message :

> ("Server: Msg 823, Level 24, State 1, Line 1 I/O error 38(Reached end
>   of file.) detected during read of BUF pointer = 0x11c01980, page ptr =
>   0x1f6bc000, pageid = (0x1:0x7bea01), dbid = 7, status = 0x801, file =
>   E:\MSSQL7\Data\Mydb_Data.MDF. Connection Broken "

I executed command with the Service Manager stopped (I don't know if it's important)
Please I'm desperate. What can I do to recover my db. 
I'm not expert in SQL Server and it would be appreciate if the answers were very clear

Comment: First do a copy of this database , and after that you can work safely on files with dbcc check and other database diagnostic tools .

Comment: Looks like an issue with the command you used. What version of SQL Server are you using? When is your latest backup?

Comment: You did the biggest mistake of your life by detaching the database. One should never do this for suspect database you almost loose all chance to recover it. I suggest you read Paul Randal Blog [Hack Attach Damaged Database](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/disaster-recovery-101-hack-attach-a-damaged-database/). Follow the steps mentioned

Comment: You can also read this blog, https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/31591/How-to-Attach-SQL-Database-Which-is-Not-Properly-Detached.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database is marked suspect and you are desperate, then I'll advice you to set the status to that database, like:

update master.dbo.sysdatabases
set status = 20
where name = 'YourDatabaseName'
Very sorry that you have no backup. 
Also have a look this Recommended       actions http://www.techrepublic.com/forums/discussions/it-seems-our-sql-database-is-corrupted/

Comment: I am very grateful for your advice. Thank you very much! The issue has been resolved.)